# Is the isomorphism $H_n(S^n) \cong H_n(U, U - x)$ "natural"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

For a point $x \in S^n$ and some neighborhood $U$ of $x$, we have an isomorphism $H_n(S^n) \cong H_n(U, U - x)$ given by the composition
$$
H_n(S^n) \xrightarrow{\cong} H_n(S^n, S^n - x) \xleftarrow{\cong} H_n(U, U - x),
$$
where the first isomorphism is from the long exact sequence of the pair $(S^n, S^n - x)$ and the second isomorphism is from excision. Intuitively, I think of this as the global orientation of $S^n$ (a fixed isomorphism $H_n(S^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$) inducing a local orientation at the point $x_i$ (a fixed isomorphism $H_n(U, U - x) \cong \mathbb{Z}$).

It seems to me that this isomorphism is "natural" in the sense that it doesn't involve any choices. There is only one way to orient the point $x$ given an orientation of $S^n$. So I'm wondering, is there a rigorous sense in which the isomorphism $H_n(S^n) \cong H_n(U, U - x)$ is natural?

Naturality does not seem to hold in the obvious way. For instance, given a continuous map $f : S^n \to S^n$ that restricts to a map $(U, U - x) \to (V, V - y)$, the following diagram does not necessarily commute:

[image]

For instance, if $f$ maps $U$ homeomorphically to $V$, then bottom map is always an isomorphism, but the top map may not be.

Comment: It is natural with respect to maps S^n \to S^n that preserve both U and x.

Comment: Notice that in the composition in your first diagram the first map is induced by an inclusion — it comes form a long exact sequence — and the second one is also induced by an inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for a map $f : S^n \to S^n$ there do not necessarily exist open neighborhooods $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $y = f(x)$ such that $f(U-x) \subset V-y$. For example, no map which is constant on some neigborhood of $x$ has this property.

The best possible result seems to be this:

Let $f : S^n \to S^n$ be map and $x \in S^n$ such that $f(S^n-x) \subset S^n -f(x)$. Then for all open neigborhoods $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $f(x)$ such that $f(U) \subset V$ the following diagram commutes:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_n(S^n) @>{f_*}>> H_n(S^n) \\
@V{j_*}V{\approx}V @V{\approx}V{j_*}V \\
H_n(S^n,S^n-x)  @>{f_*}>> H_n(S^n,S^n-f(x)) \\@A{i_*}A{\approx}A @A{\approx}A{i_*}A \\
H_n(U,U-x) @>{f_*}>> H_n(V,V-f(x))
\end{CD}